# Flink application TaskManager timeout exception Flink 1.11.2 running on EMR 6.2.1

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

We are currently running a Flink application on EMR 6.2.1 which runs on Yarn. The flink version is 1.11.2

We're running at a parallelism of 180 with 65 task nodes in EMR. When we start up the yarn application we run the following:

```
flink-yarn-session --name NameOfJob --jobManagerMemory 2048 --taskManagerMemory 32000 --slots 4 --detached
```

When the flink job is deployed it takes about 15 minutes to start up and for all the SubTasks to start running. We see several restarts and the following exception

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The heartbeat of TaskManager with id X timed out

The job then starts up but after about 20 hours of running the checkpoints start failing and again we see the exception above.

I have seen similar questions around maybe the job manager memory needs to be increased but I'm struggling to find guidance on by how much to increase it or what recommendations may be. The other issue is by the time we can look at the logs of the task manager which fails, it's been killed and the logs are gone.

Any guidance around whether increasing the job manager memory will help and by what increments we should look at doing it would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this also happening when the Task Managers get overloaded and are unable to communicate with the Job Manager. Do the checkpoints size continuously grow?

Comment: We have had the scenario when this happens (checkpoint sizes growing) but its not always the case. The maximum size of checkpoint size it got to was about 3 minutes (usually around 55 seconds)

Comment: @GerardGarcia What steps had you taken when you saw this issue?

Comment: Logs and metrics. I'd try to get the logs from EMR directly (or send them somewhere) and check for metrics that indicate if it is using all the CPU, memory or network. For example, it may not be a problem with the state size, but the TM may be running into GC hell (basically not enough heap working memory). Other thoughts: yes, 2GB of total memory for the Job Manager for a task with that much parallelism... seems a bit low. You can confirm if it is not enough by looking at the JM metrics. You can also try reducing the slots per TM to free them a bit.

Comment: We use Ganglia for the metrics and the EMR Cluster is heavily under utilised. Using about 20% of the total CPU. Network usage is also low. Looking at the various JVM metrics available as well I believe the job isn't running into GC hell. 

This is what makes me think there may be some Flink configs which aren't right for our job possibly. Adjusting the jobmanager memory to 3072 and task slots to 3 hasn't had much impact either

Comment: Adding what we believe worked for us. We re deployed the yarn application with the following resources: 

flink-yarn-session --name NameOfJob --jobManagerMemory 3072 --taskManagerMemory 32000 --slots 3 --detached 

This seems to have helped the flink jobs now as they are now running without running into the exception issue. However they still take about 20 minutes to start up when redeployed to a yarn application which was running another app previously. But so far the above has solves 90% of our problems